# Foreach through array, do some calculations within the array, then create new array and merge back into original

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

Having some difficulty trying to do this. I'm fetching an array of all submissions, and they are being returned in an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Submission] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [title] => This is a test, only a test
                    [source] => http://www.testing.com
                    [slug] => this-is-a-test-only-a-test
                    [category] => misc
                    [created] => 2012-10-05 03:43:11
                    [id] => 110
                )

            [SubmissionsVote] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 336
                            [user_id] => 2
                            [submission_id] => 110
                            [vote_type] => up
                        )

                )
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 337
                            [user_id] => 4
                            [submission_id] => 110
                            [vote_type] => down
                        )

                )
        )
)
```

My intent is to loop through that returned array, and grab all the SubmissionsVote by `vote_type` == `up` and `vote_type` == `down`.

I then want to calculate a score (this example would return a score of `0` which is just: `up` - `down`. With that, I want to put that score into an array and append it to the end of the original one so it'd look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
           [Submission] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [title] => This is a test, only a test
                    [source] => http://www.testing.com
                    [slug] => this-is-a-test-only-a-test
                    [category] => misc
                    [created] => 2012-10-05 03:43:11
                    [id] => 110
                )

            [SubmissionsVote] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 336
                            [user_id] => 2
                            [submission_id] => 110
                            [vote_type] => up
                        )

                )
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 337
                            [user_id] => 4
                            [submission_id] => 110
                            [vote_type] => down
                        )

                )
        [SubmissionScore] => Array
        (
             [0] => 0
        )
        )
)
```

Here is what I am doing unsuccessfully:

```
    $votes = array();
    $totalScore = array();

    foreach ($submissions as $submission) {
        $vote = $submission['SubmissionsVote'];
        array_push($votes, $vote);
    }   

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($votes); $i++) {
        $downVotes = 0;
        $upVotes = 0;

        if ($votes[$i]['vote_type'] == 'down') {
            $downVotes += 1;
        } else if ($votes[$i]['vote_type'] == 'up') {
            $upVotes += 1;
        }   

        $score = $upVotes - $downVotes;
        $totalScore = array_push($totalScore, $score);
    }
```

Would love to get a little push in the right direction here.

Comment: If you only want to push one element don't use `array_push()` but the `[]` syntax

Comment: @Satevis thanks did not know that before :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least two errors in your code :

- You never set `SubmissionScore` in your array to `$totalScore` value.
- Even if you add a `$votes[$i]['SubmissionScore'] = $totalScore`, that will not work, in PHP only object are passed by reference so `$votes` will only contain copy.

There are multiple possibility to resolve the problem but a [reference in the foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) is a good choice :

```
foreach ($submissions as &$submission) {
    $totalScore = 0;
    foreach ($submission['SubmissionsVote'] as $vote) {
        if ($vote['vote_type'] == 'down') {
            $totalScore--;
        } else if ($vote['vote_type'] == 'up') {
            $totalScore++;
        }
    }
    $submission['SubmissionScore'] = $totalScore;
}
```

Each submission will now have a `SubmissionScore` based on up/down vote.

Comment: Interesting. Never though about passing by reference.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
$newSubmissions = array();

foreach ($submissions as $submission) {
    $SubmissionsVote = $submission['SubmissionsVote'];

    foreach($SubmissionsVote as $votes) {
        $score = 0;
         if ($votes['vote_type'] == 'down') {
            $score -= 1;
        } else if ($votes['vote_type'] == 'up') {
            $score += 1;
        }   
        $submission['SubmissionScore'] = array($score);
    }
    $newSubmissions[] = $submission;

}

$submissions = $newSubmissions;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing $downVotes and $upVotes inside a loop, that means you override values each time you iterate through the array.

Anyway, you could simplify this.

```
foreach ($submissions as $index => $submission) {
    $up = 0;
    $down = 0;
    foreach ($submission['SubmissionsVote'] as $vote) {
        if ($vote['vote_type'] == 'up') {
            $up++;
        } else {
            $down++;
        }
    }
    $submissions[$index]['SubmissionScore'] = $up - $down;
}
```